# ¿Se puede paginar una consulta en oracle sin indice numérico?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una tabla en oracle:

```
Select nombre, clave from persona;

----------------------
NOMBRE      CLAVE
Maria       A2
Tomas       B0
Pepe        B1
Juan        C1
Sergio      D3
Angeles     H2
Pilar       J10
Roberta     R4
Izaskun     W3
Eugenio     Z1
```

Necesito poder consultar la información en bloques de 5.

He montado el ejemplo en [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/611d4/4).

Antes he probado a traerme los datos con:

```
select nombre, clave
from persona
where rownum < 5
order by clave;
```

Pero claro eso solo me vale para la primera vez.

Luego he probado otras cosas que no me han servido, en resumen no puedo consultar toda la información de la base de datos por rendimiento.

¿Conoceis alguna solución?

Comment: La forma natural y mas consistente de hacerlo, es hacer la consulta completa, agregar una clave incremental por fila, materializar la consulta en algún tipo de tabla temporal, y luego explotar esta última. Cualquier mecanismo dinámico para generar un ID por fila va a chocar con el problema que en el medio la tabla haya mutado.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho en el ejemplo que he publicado, ordenábamos los registros por fecha de modificación ascendiente, así si el registro se modificaba una vez enviado, se volvería a colocar el "ultimo" en el bucle y volvería a enviarse actualizado

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ¿Entiendo entonces que no se puede paginar la consulta con la estructura actual?

Comment: @rencinas, claro, en tu caso no importa tanto la consistencia de la consulta sino ver la información constantemente actualizada, es una cuestión de criterios. Si consideras que una consulta debiera ser la "foto" de un estado de la tabla al momento, la única forma es "congelar" los resultados y paginar sobre estos.

Comment: No, no necesariamente, lo que quería señalar es lo que le mencioné antes a rencinas, si la consulta debe ser la "foto" de un estado de la tabla, debes pasar por una tabla temporal para "congelar" los datos y luego paginar con un ID calculado. Si eso no te importa, creo que de todas formas, es posible usar el `ROWID` para paginar, revisa esto: http://dbakevin.blogspot.com/2012/04/rowid-paging-benifit-from-11g-new.html

Comment: Otro tema, estás queriendo un orden para la tabla, entiendo entonces que si o sí la consulta debe resolverse completa antes de poder paginar. Me inclino a pensar que no se puede.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho También lo creo, supongo que tendré que crear una vista para añadir la columna, o alguna solución similar.

Answer (score 3):

Ejemplo de como lo hice en la empresa para recuperar 80.000 registros y paginarlos para que los recuperara una app movil.

```
select * from(
  select main_sql.*, ROWNUM RN from(
    select nombre, clave
    from persona
    order by clave
  ) main_sql
);
```

Con eso ya tendrías tu registro con su correspondiente numero de linea, para paginar resultados, igualmente recupera todos los registros

Comment: Hola @rencinas de esa manera tengo el mismo problema que usando `rownum` que para listar tengo que hacer la consulta entera y eso mismo no puedo por rendimiento, gracias.

Comment: Que version de oracle usas? Porque yo lo tuve que hacer así "si o si" porque el cliente usa la 11c. Por otro lado de la manera que lo haces tu, solo podrías paginar los X primeros resultados. No podrías desde el 100 al 200, sino que solo los 200 primeros

Comment: Uso la 11g, el problema que veo a tú select es que al hacer: `select nombre, clave from persona order by clave` ya estamos consultando toda la tabla. Gracias!

Comment: @nachfren Te preguntaba por la versión, ya que en la 12 se puede utilizar `limit` y `offset` que evitan consultar toda la tabla. Así que si no tienes la 12.... No te queda otra.

Comment: @rencinas Buenas, he estado leyendo esta publicación y me parece interesante. Estoy teniendo el mismo problema de la versión 11. No entiendo muy bien, a la hora de pasarle que quieres que te muestre 10 registros como lo harías?, ¿Cómo le dirías desde java que necesitas mostrar los resultados de la 10 a la 20 por ejemplo?